# Text of formula in one cell used as reference for formula in cells on different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Workbook will contain dozens of sheets, and every sheet will have one cell somewhere on the sheet with a function that returns a standardized plain language phrase based on a number of lookups on that sheet. The function may be something like this:

```
="The start date was "&A1&" and resulted in "&B1
```

Each of these sheets has values in A1 & B1 unique to that sheet, so the cell references within the formula are identical across all sheets. That means A1 on every sheet is a unique start date and B1 is every sheet's unique result.

Here is the problem. The formula needs to be editable on the fly for all sheets, which is why I want to keep it on a single "master" sheet called **references** in a "master" cell named **ref_plainLang**.

Here is another problem. WHERE on each sheet this plain language formula result needs to appear differs from one sheet to another. On Sheet 1 the plain language string needs to appear in C3, but on Sheet 2 it appears in D6, and those locations may also need to change on the fly. I know how to do this with VBA but want a non-macro version because it is painful to change the location on every sheet with VBA.

Here is what does not work. In the master cell **ref_plainLang**, I place the text without the = sign:

```
"The start date was "&A1&" and resulted in "&B1
```

On a different sheet, I type

```
="="&ref_plainLang
```

and in that cell now appears the full function as it would be typed out

```
="The start date was "&A1&" and resulted in "&B1
```

but everything is still text.

I have messed around extensively with Indirect() as that seems the natural solution somehow, but can't get it to work. If the order of the text and references was unlikely to change, I would just add the function completely in each sheet by storing each section of the plain language phrase as chunks in separate cells in sheet **references**, something like this:

```
[named: ref_plainLang1] A1 = The start date was 
[named: ref_plainLang2] B1 = A1
[named: ref_plainLang3] C1 =  and resulted in
[named: ref_plainLang4] D1 = B1
```

Then string them together on Sheet 1, Sheet 2, etc. with this:

```
=ref_plainLang1&indirect(ref_plainLang2)&ref_plainLang3&indirect(ref_plainLang4)
```

I hesitate to take that approach if it can instead be done with just one named cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question, but I think you're close to what you need.  Instead of using `INDIRECT`, I would use simple defined names and either assemble them into phrases where they're needed, or (as you've already started) build the phrases in one place and assign a defined name to the completed pieces, and then reference that name.

Assuming:
Worksheet `ref_plainlang` with the following names defined:

```
name              scope     refers to  
ref_startdate     workbook  =ref_plainlang!$A$1   
ref_resulted_in   workbook  =ref_plainlang!$B$1  
ref_text          workbook  =ref_plainlang$D$1

cell  value
A1    2018-01-01
B1    $100.00
D1    ="the start date was "&TEXT(ref_startdate,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" and resulted in "&TEXT(ref_resulted_in,"$0.00")
```

With that, on another sheet, I can enter either:

```
="the start date was "&TEXT(ref_startdate,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" and resulted in "&TEXT(ref_resulted_in,"$0.00")
```

or

```
=ref_text
```

And both return the string `the start date was 2018-01-01 and resulted in $100.00`

Comment: Your solution is workable if my master worksheet is the source of the cell referenced unique data (A1 = date, B1 = $), but my master worksheet only houses the named cell ref_plainLang which contains the master function that I want spelled out on other sheets in the workbook. Those other sheets might have A1 = 5/1/2018 or A1 = 10/1/2017 or whatever - it's those non-master sheets with the changing data that function needs to grab. I hope to simply add =ref_plainLang to my dozens of sheets in whatever cell I need, and each sheet will display the function results unique to that sheet's cells.

Comment: So, on a local sheet you want to reference the master function (from ref_plainlang) but with variables from the local sheet inserted in the master function?

Comment: Exactly. Each local sheet uses the same function, but the values in the cells A1, B1, etc. on each local sheet is different so the full ref_plainLang result is different for every sheet even though they all spit out the same standardized phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

So the desired formula stays in one place, but where you wish to use it will differ from page to page.

No problem. You just use absolute referencing in your address for where the template formula resides.

This would be harder if the page's input cells moved about as well, especially if they did not do so keeping the same relative location to the cell where this result is desired.

The difficulty, of course, is just WHERE do you actually make that absolute reference?

The answer is:  In a Named Range. There is a reason for that which I'll address later.

So, create a Named Range, perhaps called `Result_ref_plainLang` or `ref_plainLang_Result`. You clearly know how to do that since you've named the cell the formula is in.

Related:  check the Named Range `ref_plainLang` and make sure the cell with the template formula is addressed absolutely. So if C1 on that master sheet, it would be $C$1 in the Named Range. (This would not matter if the formula did not move around from page to page.)

The next problem is how to make the formula work. Given the small difficulty about to arise and your seemingly not-beginner Excel knowledge, I bet you know I'm headed toward using `EVALUATE()` in the Result Named Range ("NR") and I'll further guess you tried that and it didn't work out.

It won't, of course, because you're telling it to do a two-level Evaluation and it isn't so good at that. If you wrap the master formula with the `FORMULATEXT()` function, that will bring it into the `EVALUATE()` function as one single entity and it then works:

```
=EVALUATE(FORMULATEXT(Sheet1!$C$3))
```

(if the template formula were in C3 on Sheet1).

```
=EVALUATE(FORMULATEXT(ref_plainLang))
```

(to use the Named Range name).

Naturally, you could do all this in a single Named Range if you prefer. Just include the formula directly where I placed the Named Range `ref_plainLang`. It still has to go inside the `FORMULATEXT()` function. Just use the name you have already, changing its `Refers to` to this formula. Or keep two names so you have an easier time editing it as the current NR would have nothing but the template formula, or a reference to it. (Absolute reference, of course.)

By the way, if the referenced cells

This WILL update any time its page's A1 or B1 change. That means there's no need to add something like `+TODAY()*0` to it. If it matters to you (as in, your spreadsheet is massive enough that it affects calculation speed), this is not volatile in the way `INDIRECT()` would be.